# How to prove that a collection of functions is uniformly absolutely continuous if $\sup_n \int |f_n|^{1+\gamma}\ d\mu < \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f_1, f_2, \dotsc$ is a collection of measurable functions which satisfy $\sup_n \int |f_n|^{1 + \gamma}\ d\mu< \infty$ for some $\gamma > 0$, and $\mu$ is a finite measure. I am being asked to show that the $\{f_n\}$ are uniformly absolutely continuous. That is, for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $A$ with $\mu(A) < \delta$ $$\int_{A} |f_n|\ d\mu < \epsilon$$ for all $n \geq 1$.

I'm not sure how to use the fact that $\sup_n \int |f_n|^{1 + \gamma}\ d\mu< \infty$. If I assume only that $\sup_n \int |f_n|\ d\mu< \infty$, it seems I can prove something weaker:

Suppose $A_1, A_2, \cdots$ is any sequence of sets for which $\mu(A_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, and let $m \geq 1$. Since $f_m \cdot 1_{A_n} \to 0$ a.e. and $|f_m \cdot 1_{A_n}| \leq |f_m|$ and $\int |f_m| < \infty$, the dominated convergence theorem implies that $\int_{A_n} |f_m| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

But I'm not sure where to go from here. I think this can be done by first proving that the $f_n$ are uniformly integrable, but I would like to find a direct proof if possible.

Comment: I guess you mean to say **uniformly integrable**, not *uniformly absolutely continuous*? For functions that are defined on a measure space there isn't really a definition of continuity.

Comment: @HansEngler See exercise 7.21 on pg. 66 of this book: http://bass.math.uconn.edu/v42.pdf. I gave the definition in my question.

Comment: Use Hölder's inequality.

Comment: @DanielFischer with $p = 1 + \gamma$ and $q = (1 + \gamma) / \gamma$?

Comment: Actually, the conclusion continues to hold if  $\gamma >0$. I remember that $L^p$-bounded (for $p>1$, $p=1$ does not work.) implies that the family is uniformly integrable. Moreover, the family needs not be countable.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Sorry $\gamma > 0$ is what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p=1+\gamma$. Then $\frac1q=\frac{p-1}{p}=\frac{\gamma}{1+\gamma}$ so $q=\frac{1+\gamma}{\gamma}$. By Holder's inequality,

$\int_A |f_n|\,d\mu \leq \|f_n\|_p\|1\|_q=\left[\int_A |f_n|^{1+\gamma}\,d\mu\right]^{\frac{1}{1+\gamma}}\left[\mu(A)\right]^{\frac{\gamma}{1+\gamma}}\leq \left[\sup_n\int_X |f_n|^{1+\gamma}\,d\mu\right]^{\frac{1}{1+\gamma}}\left[\mu(A)\right]^{\frac{\gamma}{1+\gamma}}  .$
It should be clear how to pick $\delta(\epsilon)$ so that the above is bounded above by $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why do we need that $\mu$ is finite to prove this?

Comment: Otherwise, the bound obtained by Holders is trivial, as you are then just saying an integral is at most infinity.

Comment: Is that because of the $\mu(A)$ term? I don't understand. $M = \sup_n \int_{A} |f_n|^{1+\gamma}$ is finite by assumption, and if the bound holds for all $A$ then we can choose $\delta = (\epsilon/M^{1/p})^q$, right?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I don't think you actually need it. See my edit. In the last inequality, it's convenient to change $A$ to $X$ in the sup term. That way, it's easy to solve for $\delta$ by isolating the $\mu(A)$ term.

Comment: The measure space doesn't need to be finite. I don't believe so at least. Are there more parts to this question where the finiteness was needed?